# Setting Custom Docks for ALL users in Mavericks?

Tags: icons, osx-mavericks, dock

I work in a domain setting where the domain is managed by Active Directory. The macs are set up with domain logins, no local profiles. I am trying to set the default dock for Mavericks. I used to copy the com.apple.dock.plist file into the template English.proj in the system templates file (basic instructions for Mountain Lion). Everything I have read about Mavericks docks settings suggest that I cannot set the dock for all users any more this way because of cached preferences?

All I see in preferences now is com.apple.dockfixtup.com? I tried copying that file over and it did not work. I usually follow these instructions https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100188/osx-10-8-how-to-keep-a-custom-dock-for-all-users-that-login

Anyone have any way of setting the dock preferences for all users that login?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not really a programming question, and probably better suited to one of the other StackExchange sites.

Comment: as @Abizern said, this belongs on superuser.com

Comment: @Markasoftware Okay thank you I will post it there.